# Parallel Boost Graph Library simple example not linking correctly

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I really need some help to run my first Parallel Boost Graph Library example.

Right now I'm trying to use this one: https://github.com/boostorg/graph_parallel/blob/master/example/dijkstra_shortest_paths.cpp

The problems start on distributed graph creation:

```
Graph g(reader.begin(), reader.end(), reader.weight_begin(),
          reader.num_vertices());
```

If I remove it and the following code, everything compiles just fine. If I add this string - a lot of errors, like

```
boost::enable_if<boost::mpi::is_mpi_datatype<unsigned long>, void>::type boost::graph::distributed::send_oob<unsigned long>(boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group const&, int, int, unsigned long const&, int) in cc6AGjMu.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

just overwhelm me. The full list of errors I provide here:    https://pastebin.com/post.php    `<- errors there`

I have latest boost release 1.65.1 (I also tried 1_64, 1_55, and some others with the same result). I also tried using it on 2 different systems: my mac os laptop, and my university supercomputer (where everything, for example MPI, is set up correctly).

I use the following command to compile the example file:

```
mpic++ -fopenmp -O3 -std=c++11 -fpermissive -I boost_1_65_1/ PBGL_test.cpp -o  PBGL_test -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lboost_system
```

Where PBGL_test.cpp is the example file I linked above.

I understand that, most probably, I forgot to link some important library, but I have no idea which one exactly, and I can't find the solution or similar problems in the web.

If anyone have any ideas what else I need to link, or have a working example of PBGL distributed graphs usage (with makefile or just instructions how to compile them) - please, link them here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You almost gave the name of the missing lib in your title...

Comment: Yes, now I looked again and found libboost_graph_parallel. I'm stupid, thank you very much.

Comment: Also, the pastebin link is borked